# Getting an element from an array of symbols

Tags: ruby

I have an array of symbols and I am trying to get one from it, or return nil if its not found

```
plugins = [:one, :two, :three]
def resolve_plugin(name)
  plugins[:"#{name}_plugin"]
end
```

When I call `resolve_plugin(:one)` I get `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: `plugins` is an array, not a hash, so you just want `plugins.include?(name.to_sym) ? name.to_sym : nil`. If `name` is already a symbol, drop `to_sym`.

Answer (score 0):

An `Array` maps indices to objects, so you access it by index, not by value:

```
plugins = [:one, :two, :three]

plugins[0] # => :one
plugins[2] # => :three
```